How should I create a concept design example?
I'm new to freelance and want to send a design proposal to a company, even though I'm still new I want to look professional by setting a good timeline and schedule.
However, I was confused at the beginning when I was going to present the concept, whether I had to bring an example that I made myself or is it ok to take design references from the internet?
If I have to make the design myself, is there a way to avoid wasting too much time at the start? or is it normal that the designer should make many design concepts first? because I don't want to set the price too high, the design services I want to offer is social media content design.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Has the company requested that you create a concept design?  You can't generally use other peoples designs for anything, as they are automatically copyright, and belong to the original creator. You could be sued for using copyrighted material.

Hi. No, actually I just want to offer some concepts designs to that company and I just thinking to take references from designs on the internet, I know about copyright and other things but I just want to know if it ok to take other designs just for refrence to client. Because if I make my own concepts designs it will take time and increase costs, but I don't mind if it's the right answer, I just want to make sure everything.

Are planning on just "cold calling" the client or have you been asked for a proposal? Honestly, if you are cold calling, no "concepts" are necessary, just a good portfolio which relates to the field the client is in. Most clients don't take kindly to some random person stating "your stuff sucks, here's how I can do better" approach. If you've been asked, then there should be a fee structure in place to compensate for any time needed for an effective concept proposal.

It's not OK to use other peoples designs for advertising your services. That would be commercial use and would most likely be copyright infringement.  It's OK to look at other's work for inspiration.  I don't really get what you are asking here to be honest. Why would you want to show a potential client somebody else's work?  This doesn't seem honest to me.  Also, any kind of cold calling is pretty unprofessional IMHO.

I want to clarify I dont want to be liar or unprofessional toward client and I just want to know how I should presented various concept to client after the agreement of the proposal. But now I know that not ok to put other ppl designs. I'm sorry for my poor english.
